# Use imported library in imported module

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to use `time.strftime()` via a function from another file but for some reason the import of `time` library is not working (if I omit the `import time` the output looks exactly the same):

foo.py:

```
import bar

print bar.test()
print bar.time()
```

bar.py:

```
import time

def test():
    return "check!"

def time():
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Output:

```
import_test>python foo.py
check!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    print bar.time()
  File "import_test\bar.py", line 7, in time
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: try renaming your function to something other than your imported module. you are overwriting the namespace.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I made that code as easy example for my actual code. My test code is working if I change the function name, with my actual code it's still not working.

Comment: But seems like I was still overwriting something. Changed module and function name and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining funvtion time() that has the same time as imported module time, thus an error message: 'function' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Rename your function to Time() and it should work (I guess)